# Question about the use of \multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn

My question is probably quite simple but I do not know how to solve it. 
I have two stata table that I am trying to merge (I use stata options for latex). I want to add a title on my new table. I thus understood that I needed to use \multicolumn but I try different things and nothing seems to work.

```
{
\def\onepc{$^{\ast\ast}$} \def\fivepc{$^{\ast}$}
\def\tenpc{$^{\dag}$}
\def\legend{\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize{Significance levels
:\hspace{1em} $\dag$ : 10\% \hspace{1em}
$\ast$ : 5\% \hspace{1em} $\ast\ast$ : 1\% \normalsize}}}
\begin{table}[H]\centering
 \caption{Estimation results : regress
\label{tabresult regress}}
\begin{tabular}{l r @{} l c ||c c}\hline\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{OLS regression}} & {\textbf{Probit regression}}\\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{c}
{\textbf{Variable}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Coefficient}}  & \textbf{(Std. Err.)} & {\textbf{Coefficient}}  & \textbf{(Std. Err.)} \\ \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
```

What it looks like for now. We see that it's quite strange and not harmonious.

[image]

I want the "OLS regression" to be in the middle of the bloc constituted by the 3 columns from the second line (variable, coefficient, std err), then a separate line, and then the "probit regression" in the middle of the bloc constituted by the 2 columns from the second line (coefficient, std err). 
Would someone could give me a hand on this? 
Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your MWE is not possible to be sure, what you like to achieve. Based on my guessing I format the following table:

[image]

To obtain it is quite straightforward. I hope that code is easy to understand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
My question is probably quite simple but I do not know how to solve it. I have two stata table that I am trying to merge (I use stata options for latex). I want to add a title on my new table. I thus understood that I needed to use \verb+\multicolumn+ but I try different things and nothing seems to work.

    \begin{table}[htb]\centering
\caption{Estimation results: regress}
    \label{tabresult regress}
\begin{tabular}{l c  c ||c c}\hline\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c||}{\textbf{OLS regression}} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Probit regression}}\\
    \hline
\thead{Variable}
    &   \thead{Coefficient}
        &   \thead{(Std. Err.)} 
            &   \thead{Coefficient}  
                &   \thead{(Std. Err.)}             \\ 
    \hline
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5                             \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In comparison to your MWE I erase one spurious column (do you with combination `rl` like to format numbers at decimal point? If this is case, than you need diferent type of column, which better manage adjusting of numbers, for example `S` from `siunitx` package). add package `makecell` for simpler seting of column heads. The "Probit regression" is now in own `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}`

I didnt bother with table design, but I encourage you to look for ˙booktabs` package, which enable "profesional" table settings. To provide an example, you need to add least one row of table content.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko, that was exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: @Antoine, if you really liked it, you can accept answer :-). However,  don't rush, maybe some one will propose betters solution ... Happy TeX-ing!